# Ubuntu won't boot in to gui after latest sudo apt upgrade

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, graphics

I am not super knowledgeable about much of ubuntu's inner workings. I only understand some of the basics, but after I ran the latest apt upgrade command I saw when glancing at the packages being installed that there was some kind of nvidia package being run and unpackaged. Ever since I have installed ubuntu I have had periodic problems with some upgrades where the nvidia driver seems to either not be recognized by grub or ubuntu because it boots into the operating system, but only with a basic text flashing cursor displayed. I can navigate the system as though I was using terminal, but can do nothing else.

I am unclear why this is happening. I have a MSI GT683R computer running a NVIDIA GTX 560M video card. The two drivers it is trying to work with right now are

nvidia-driver-390 (this has been the recommended one which I have used in the past and has worked fine)
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

If someone could help me figure out what is going on that would be great. My system has worked well for over a year or more and I have done several upgrades in that time and not had this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you select grub when booting and boot into an older kernel? There have been many reports similar to this with the newest kernel.

Comment: I am sorry, can you spell out for me how to do that?

Comment: If you don't see a grub screen when booting, hold down ESC after powering on the computer. A screen should appear where there's a choice of "advanced options for Ubuntu". Select that (arrow keys and enter key) and then select an option with a kernel number less that the top one. Don't select the entry with (recovery mode) in it.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Looks like that did it thank you! Will I have to manually select that GRUB version every time I boot?

Comment: New problem. My network card seems to no longer be working or something. I can't even configure an ethernet port in settings.

Comment: No idea on the card. If it worked in the old kernel in the past, I would think it would work now. As far as setting the old kernel to boot by default, this answer gives a way, although it's kind of old https://askubuntu.com/a/419173/243321  This is just a stopgap though, you will need to get kernel updates eventually, hopefully they will fix the newer kernels. There have been lots of problem reports. Best wishes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doesn't boot to desktop environment after updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499759/doesnt-boot-to-desktop-environment-after-updates)