System hangs up when switching from Windows to Ubuntu
I have installed Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. Both systems work properly. Switching from Ubuntu to Windows is no problem, but switching from Windows to Ubuntu the system hangs up.
When launching Ubuntu I first get the message:
/dev/sdb4: clean, .. files, .. blocks
.. usb ..
.. r8169 0000:04.0 enp4s0: rtl_ocp_gphy_cond == 1 (loop: 10, delay: 25).
Then the system hangs up.
After reboot I get:
/dev/sdb4: recovering journal
/dev/sdb4: Clearing orphaned inode …
/dev/sdb4: clean, .. files, .. blocks  
Then Ubuntu launches and works properly.
How can I find out what’s going wrong here?
Why has the journal to be recovered?

The recovered journal is because you used the power switch to power off the machine, perfectly normal. Read the journal contents if you want to see the details. Your first message seems to be incomplete, an edited message?

This question is similar to: "dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What do you mean by "switching from Windows to Ubuntu"? Can you be more specific about the details of what you are doing?

General answer:
In a multi-OS computer...
The OS that you leave is better be in a "clean state" if you intend to use the other OS.
This is not the case if you have e.g. put Windows to sleep and then force power off to run e.g. Ubuntu.
So; this is especially important w.r.t. hibernation, sleep mode and disks / drives / partitions that get used from the active OS.
A hibernated OS has "tricks" to keep it possible to restart from hibernation. Those tricks are generally "not supported" by the other OS:es.
Removable drives, USB-memory and such has to be cleanly "umnounted" (Eject on Windows), and the OS has to be "shut down" - only then you have a 'clean state'.

Windows Shutdown or Restart should be equal to a "clean state" w.r.t. Windows.  

Seems windows leaves something in an "unclean" state; might be some hardware that is left in a state that isn't recognizable by Linux, e.g. most importantly; not in same state as when powering on.
Grub menu: Advanced > Recovery mode > menu opts: fsck, network, root > Enter: will leave you at a bash prompt as root (admin) user.
All files in /var/log/ will tell details, less file to look in file, zcat file | less to look in files with names ending in .gz

Thanks for explaining the 'clean state'. When I 'switch from Windows to Ubuntu' I select 'restart' in Windows and then in GRUB I select 'Ubuntu'. Does this violate the 'clean state'?

And why does the system stop responding (hangs up, freeze up) when GRUB launches Ubuntu (this only happens when Windows was active before)? How and where can I find a log?

Updated text above.

Thanks for your answer.   In opts I performed fsck, grub, .., no error was found. Using root I checked the files in /var/log. There are 29 gz-files with tons of log messages. Do you have any idea what I can search for?   Now when I select Ubuntu 20.04 in the GRUB menu I get the error: file /boot/vmlinuz-6.6.0-15-generic not found. You have to load the kernel first. Type any key to continue. Only the Advanced mode works. How can I resolve this?

Go into recovery mode and install a suitable "linux-image". dpkg --list | grep linux-image, apt install kernel-image-... will install it properly. Make sure to apt purge ... your broken one.

dpkg --list | grep linux-imagelists several kernel images and the generic kernel image. Latest kernel image is 6.5.0.45. How do I find the broken one and how do I purge it? How do I apt install it? Sorry, but I'm not very familiar with Linux.

Sorry, vmlinuz-6.6.0-15-generic "not found" indicates that you have a broken or half installed kernel-image-6.6.0-15-... - this name would appear in the second column of the output of  dpkg --list | grep linux-image - copy that name and paste it after apt purge ... instead of the dots. Then apt install ... any other (i.e. at least one) kernel-image-... to get Linux to actually boot.

Great, my issue is solved! I now can switch (using GRUB) from Windows to Ubuntu without getting a system freeze. Thanks a lot for your help. Installing  linux image 6.5.0-15 (the missing one according to GRUB > Ubuntu 20.04) solved the issue. After that my network (ethernet) connection was gone. Advanced > recovery mode > menu opts > network solved this issue. But one question is left: ´dpkg --list | grep linux-image´ listed 13 linux kernels, now 14. Why are there so many, isn’t one enough? And why does GRUB select the 6.5.0-15 and not 6.5.0-45 , which seems to be newer?

Try -45, if it actually works, then just remove -15 with apt purge ... The other kernel-images are probably older ones, might also be that if you try one, you still get the newest; maybe even the hwe -version. (Hardware Enablement Stack -version) ->  read https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe

right, -45 works. I purged -15, but then I again got the error: 'vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-gerneric not found' when selecting 'ubuntu 20.04' in GRUB, see above. I again installed -15. Then the error was gone. But still -15 has no network access (LAN). Repairing the network in advanced mode doesn't help. So I use -45 via advanced mode, which has LAN access. Now my question is: how can I force GRUB using -45 instead of -15 when selecting 'ubuntu 20.04'?

$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub;sudo update-grub - read up on the GRUB_DEFAULT=... option.

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved" and GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"is already set. This sets the selected default in GRUB menu, but doesn't solve my problem. My problem is that selecting Ubuntu 20.04in GRUB menu leads to kernel -15, the one without LAN access. I require kernel -45, which works properly. How can I achieve that selecting Ubuntu 20.04 leads to kernel -45?

GRUB_DEFAULT=  is to be the the INDEX (number) of the menu item to select for items on the top level in the menu, I do not remember how it was to select submenu items.  >>  sudo grep  -Po '^([ \t]*(menuentry|submenu) (.).+?\3)' /boot/grub/grub.cfg to show the content of the grub / boot menu.

Your grepshows the GRUB menu correcty. Selected submenu items are saved too. This all works as it is supposed to be. But my issue is that when I select the first item Ubuntu 20.04 in the GRUB menu kernel -15 is launched. How is this controlled and what needs to be done that kernel -45 is used instead?

You set up GRUB_DEFAULT= to point into the submenu where -45 is!!

Clear Hints - https://askubuntu.com/q/419152/289138 - adapt to your situation.
