# How can I remove my lastest Ubuntu recovery?

Tags: uninstall, grubrescue

I had problem with wireless network in Ubuntu 14.04 after installing og re-installation of packages it create more problems for me, and now I can not boot Ubuntu. My question is how can i remove my lastest Ubuntu 3.16.0-57-generic so I can boot one of the old, for example 3.16.056 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the image you posted is from Grub, you do not need to remove anything to boot into a different kernel.  Just select it in Grub at boot time.

Comment: I'm new in this field! What I have undersod is in GRUB I can select Ubuntu or Advanced option for Ubuntu, and this is the picture from the Advanced option. 
Yes I can boot from the old ones (from 3.16.0-30 to 3.16.0-56) but there is a problem in 3.16.0-57 and I want to remove it! 
So when I turn my pc on then I don't have to go to Advanced option and select one of those each time !

Comment: You can either set the kernel you want to boot from as the default in grub (it does not have to be the latest) or you can delete the newest one.  Search the site, there are many questions related to both options.  Here is one. http://askubuntu.com/questions/419116/how-to-remove-latest-kernel-without-removing-linux-itself

Comment: @naman what problem are you having with wireless? maybe you should post another question regarding this issue.