# Incorrect resolution and no wifi and no usb after update

Tags: wireless, 16.04, usb

My laptop was working fine, but I have installed some updates and after restarting, suddenly my resolution changed. I tried to change the resolution but highest resolution is already set. Wifi is not working and neither are any of the USB ports. If I open terminal, a part of the terminal window goes beyond the screen. When I boot to Windows, everything works fine. So I am sure there is no hardware problem. What is the reason behind this and how can I fix it?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried booting the previous kernel to see if that's related?

Comment: @ElderGeek How could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an issue with a kernel update. If so from the grub menu choose Advanced, and cursor down to a previously numbered kernel entry and select it. If booting a previous kernel resolves the issue you should [file a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) against the kernel that exhibited the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but I don't know how to do it . Could you tell me or a link

Comment: @shuvro See here: [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](http://askubuntu.com/q/82140/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea and Elder Geek thanks ,  My problem solved,  the version  Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-43  , but then I choose Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-42 , it solves . Could you please tell me  , how can I load  4.4.0-42 by default ?

Comment: @shuvro See http://askubuntu.com/questions/106031/how-can-i-remove-new-kernel-versions-after-downgrading/106053#106053 Simply change the number string in the answer to match the one you wish to remove.