# 16.04 Update killed network and USB connections

Tags: networking, 16.04, updates, bluetooth

I get network UNCLAIMED for both Ethernet Controller (Realtek) and Network Controller (Ralink) after the latest update from Ubuntu for 16.04.  Both have physical ID of 0.

I've tried numerous 'fixes' but have found nothing that works.

Please help.  And, because I have no internet connection, it makes it difficult for me to provide more information.

Thanks for your help, Jim.

Comment: That means there aren't any drivers installed. What wireless/bluetooth cards are they, specifically?

Comment: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe, Ralink Corp.  RT3290 Bluetooth, Ralink Corp.

Comment: Now, after messing with the BIOS settings, I've discovered that no USB ports are recognized.  I was hoping to do a backup before this gets completely out of hand.  I'm using a HP Pavilion Laptop.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What BIOS settings did you mess with? Some screenshots of your BIOS could help.

Comment: I have a similar problem: neither wired nor wireless networks work after reboot. I found no solution yet...

Comment: How do I attach screenshots here?

Comment: Have reset Bios to defaults. Had to do this often after Ubuntu updates in order to restore internet access.  This time, however, no network and no usb ports are working.  I would be happy to provide photos of my Bios settings, but this system doesn't seem to accomodate.  Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, so I got usb and network responding again by inserting a DVD Ubuntu 16.04.1 boot disk.  So, what appears to be the real issue is that the OS didn't properly update or got corrupted somehow.  I should note that 'Ubuntu Software' shows a OS update, but when I press install, it just goes on forever without finishing, and without a network connection, cannot update.   So, my question now is how do I reinstall 16.04.1 without losing all the data on my hard drive?  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar issue two days ago. Solved it by removing the latest kernel, like explained here: [How can I remove new kernel versions after downgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106031/how-can-i-remove-new-kernel-versions-after-downgrading#106053)

Comment: Thanks Konsta.  But I don't have Synaptic, nor any way of downloading it without a network connection.

Comment: Finally got it sorted:

Comment: Finally got it sorted out.   used:  cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg to find out which headers were present.   Then used: sudo apt-get remove 'linux-headers-4.4.0-43*' 'linux-image-4.4.0-43*'.  This reverted the OS to the previous version, which then booted properly, giving me full access to usb ports and internet.   That was fun.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Good reminder to me. It certainly would have been a good idea to mention, that if you don't have Synaptic installed the apt/apt-get can do the same trick... Glad you got it fixed nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it sorted out.

used: cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg to find out which headers were present.

Then used: sudo apt-get remove 'linux-headers-4.4.0-43*' 'linux-image-4.4.0-43*'.

This reverted the OS to the previous version, which then booted properly, giving me full access to usb ports and internet.

That was fun. Thanks everyone for your help.